# Less CSS (lessc) - how can I cast a string to a number while retaining CSS units?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, type-conversion, concatenation

I’ve got a Bootstrap variable setting font size in pixels - `@font-size-base: 14px;` - lovely. But I want to access that 14px value using a dynamically created variable name:

`@size = ‘base’; // or 'large', 'small' etc.
@someFontSizeVar = ~'@{font-size-@{size}}’;`

Trouble is, that kind of interpolation outputs a string, i.e. `’14px’` so I can no longer run Maths functions on it:

`round(~'@{font-size-@{size}}’); // Fails`

I need to get the interpolated output back into the format/type it was in when it was just `@font-size-base: 14px;` - I’m not sure exactly what that was, it behaved like a number, but I’m not sure it really is one because of the `px` on the end. Haven’t found much in the way of string-to-number conversion functions in Less yet.

Basically I need numberWithUnits('14px') but that's wishful thinking :) I have found the color function which does exactly this to give you back a color object (`color(~'@{btn-@{someVar}-bg}')`) but nothing yet for numbers/CSS font size units.

(The px could be em, rem, etc. etc.)

Thanks,

Gareth

Answer (score 1):

Instead of abusing nested string interpolations (those were never meant to be used as indirect variable referencing facility) use normal [variable references](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names):

```css
@font-size-base: 16px;
@size: base;


p {
   @s: "font-size-@{size}";
   font-size: round(@@s);
}
```